# How to prove that $2x^3+6x+1=0$ has no integer solution?

Tags: proof-verification, cubics

How can it be shown that $2x^3 + 6x + 1 = 0$ has no integer solutions?

I've used the intermediate value theorem to prove that there exists a *real* number $c$ between $f(-1)$ and $f(0)$ such that $f(c) = 0$, but I know that it's not enough since I need to prove that for all roots of $x$ (which I cannot assume to be only one). Based on *Desmos Graphing Calculator*, the function has only one roots. But how can I prove it?

Here is what the graph of the function looks like:
[image: Function graph]

Comment: The rational root theorem?

Comment: Yeah, that's another solution I've thought and it is not viable for the problem (I think?) because I've tried it already and no possible roots could lead the function to zero.

Comment: Yes that's because all roots are irrational and hence not integers...

Comment: Your statement of the IVT seems to be incorrect. You say that there is a real $c$ between $f(-1)$ and $f(0)$ such that $f(c)=0$.  I believe that you mean that you have found $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) = 0$ (this would be the correct consequence of the IVT, in any event).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For an integer $x$, $2x^3+6x$ is always even, whereas $1$ is always odd. Thus, the sum can not be even. Especially it cant be $0$, which is an even number as well.

Comment: Can I ask if I got your statement correct. You're saying that since the sum would always be odd, then zero (an even number) cannot be the sum of the function given that x is an integer, unless it is rational. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I improved the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know Differential calculus?

We define

$f(x)=2x^3+6x+1$.

$f'(x)=6x^2+6>0$ $(x∈R)$

So $f(x)$ monotonically increases.

$f(0)>0$,$f(-1)<0$

Therefore $f(x)$ has one solution between $-1$ and $0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

We have that for $x\in\mathbb Z$

- for $x\ge 0 \implies 2x^3+6x+1\ge 1$
- for $x< 0 \implies x(2x^2+6)+1\le -7$